# Uncaught CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout - Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, curl, ssl, sdk

I get the following error on my website in Facebook PHP SDK:
"*Uncaught CurlException: 28: SSL connection timeout*"

The code worked fine until today, and there wasn't any change on the server.

I tried to add the cURL option "**CURLOPT_SSLVERSION = 3**" to base_facebook.php, but it didn't work.

I downloaded the latest Facebook PHP SDK, and tried to open the example.php, but there was the same error.

I tried to make a DNS flush, and I modified the DNS settings to Google's public DNS addresses, but it didn't help.

> **Open SSL section in phpinfo():**
>
> - OpenSSL support    enabled
> - OpenSSL Library Version    OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
> - OpenSSL Header Version OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
>
> **cURL section in phpinfo:**
>
> - cURL support   enabled
> - cURL Information   7.21.0
> - SSL Version    OpenSSL/0.9.8o

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the URL is that the SDK is calling ? Can you open that https:// url in your browser ?

Comment: You might want to try out the various CURLOPT_*TIMEOUT options, such as CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT. see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: SDK calling the following URL: https://api.facebook.com/ I pinged this URL from the server: "ping api.facebook.com
PING star.c10r.facebook.com (31.13.64.48) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from edge-star-shv-04-ams2.facebook.com (31.13.64.48): icmp_req=1 ttl=90 time=32.1 ms". The options: TIMEOUT = 60, CONNECTTIMEOUT = 10, i tried to increase this values, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the solution:**

I blocked all IPv6 connection on my debian server:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

And now I can connect again to Facebook server with the API.

I don't know why I have to disable the IPv6 connections, but it works now.